# Send web access logs to private S3 bucket using user-data

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I am working on a project where in I have to send web access logs to a private S3 bucket, using a bash script that will be included in the user-data.tpl of the EC2 instance, so far I have:

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
exec > >(tee /var/log/user-data.log|logger -t user-data ) 2>&1
echo BEGIN
date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
yum update -y
yum install -y httpd
cat <<'EOF' >> /var/www/html/index.html
<html>
<head>
<title>Success!</title>
<style>
body {
background-image: url('https://ce-test-bg-image-onica.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/onica.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello Onica!</h1>
</body>
</html>
EOF
systemctl start httpd
systemctl enable httpd
```

I don't know how to send web access logs to a private S3 bucket,whose name is "ifecycle-testing12345", I am not sure what to add in the bash script for that.

Comment: Do you just want to copy that single file once (just after the system boots up)? When will this script run? If it runs as part of User Data, then it doesn't make sense to send the User Data log file before the User Data has finished running.

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate answer depends on what you are doing with the logs after you get them into S3.  A close answer is that you might want to install the cloudwatch logs agent on your instance, configure it to monitor the httpd logs, and have them automatically sent to cloudwatch.  Of course, your logs are now in cloudwatch instead of S3, but if you really wanted, you could export them periodically to S3 and/or configure the cloudwatch logs rotation time to whatever time is appropriate for your application.

Alternatively, if you really wanted them uploaded to S3, you could instead install a cron job in your script to periodically upload (or sync) the log file to S3.  This may not be desirable since you may overwrite the old log entries and/or have to upload the entire log file each time (as opposed to just uploading the new events in the log).

There are other tools that help with this problem (log forwarding and aggregation).  You may want to look at tools such as fluent-bit or filebeat which do a really great job at monitoring log files and forwarding them somewhere else.  fluent-bit even has a native output to S3.  However, it may not look like you expect since it will show up in that bucket as a sequence of files (of the monitored file), with each new file representing some number of new lines to the monitored file.  That is because fluent-bit is rarely used by itself, but typically in conjunction with tools like fluentd which them ingest those and aggregate them into something like elasticsearch.

Your use case and appetite for complexity will likely drive your chosen solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will be creating a cron-job for everyday logging, any headsup on where I could probably start ? TIA.